# Continuously changing the width of an element with setInterval( )

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I want to change the width of a `span` element inside a `h1` element that have the textContent changed every 4s with `setInterval()`.I want to do that to add a transition to the width property to fill the space between the `h1` and the next word that `span` will have smoothly.

I tried to get the width of the `span` with `getBoundingClientRect()` but that didn't work and when I set the width it remains the width of the first element and it's not changed dynamically as I would want.

Here is the code:

```js
const changingSpan = document.querySelector('.changing-span');
let array = ['best', 'tastiest', 'freshest'];
let count = 0;

setInterval(function() { 
    count++;
    let elementWidth = changingSpan.getBoundingClientRect().width.toString();
    if(count === array.length) count = 0;
    changingSpan.classList.add('animation-span');
    changingSpan.textContent = array[count];
    changingSpan.style.width = `${elementWidth}px`;
    changingSpan.addEventListener('animationend', function() {
    changingSpan.classList.remove('animation-span');
    })
  }, 4000);
```

```css
.changing-span {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #c82929;
    transition: width .2s ease;
}

.animation-span {
    animation: moveDown .8s ease;
}

@keyframes moveDown {
    0% {opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="first-heading">The <span class="changing-span">best</span> burgers in town.</h1>
```

Comment: Use two `span` elements, nested. The inner one should be the one you measure to get the width of the word. The outer one should be the one you set the width of. That way there's no hard-set width left over from the last word on the `span` you're trying to measure.

Comment: I tried that but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Actually, i didn't understand the answer then.Now that i finally got it that was it, all i needed was to wrap the span in another span. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

consider an animation using max-width:

```js
const changingSpan = document.querySelector('.changing-span');
let array = ['best', 'tastiest', 'freshest'];
let count = 0;

setInterval(function() {
  count++;
  if (count === array.length) count = 0;
  changingSpan.classList.add('animation-span');
  changingSpan.textContent = array[count];
  changingSpan.addEventListener('animationend', function() {
    changingSpan.classList.remove('animation-span');
  })
}, 4000);
```

```css
.changing-span {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #c82929;
}

.animation-span {
  animation: moveDown .8s ease;
}

@keyframes moveDown {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    max-width:0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
    max-width:200px; /* a big value here */
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="first-heading">The <span class="changing-span">best</span> burgers in town.</h1>
```

Comment: Thank you, but i don't like the effect. I want something like the frist heading on stackoverflow homepage if that is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very good.
But you need to remove 2 rows like below, then you code works well as you want

let elementWidth = changingSpan.getBoundingClientRect().width.toString();
changingSpan.style.width = `${elementWidth}px`;

Comment: Yes it works, but when a new word is added and the sentence is resized it happens immediately and i want it to close the gap between the words smooth.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer was posted by Sean above(Thank you). I will put here the code snippet for this in case somebody will search for something similar and will want to do the same thing:

```js
const changingSpan = document.querySelector('.changing-span');
const changingSpanWrapper = document.querySelector('.changing-span-wrapper');
let array = ['best', 'tastiest', 'freshest'];
let count = 0;

changingSpanWrapper.style.width = `${changingSpan.getBoundingClientRect().width.toString()}px`;
setInterval(function() { 
    count++;
    if(count === array.length) count = 0;
    changingSpan.classList.add('animation-span');
    changingSpan.textContent = array[count];
    changingSpan.addEventListener('animationstart', function() {
      let elementWidth = changingSpan.getBoundingClientRect().width.toString();
      let elementHeight = changingSpan.getBoundingClientRect().height.toString();
      changingSpanWrapper.style.width = `${elementWidth}px`;
      changingSpanWrapper.style.height = `${elementHeight}px`;
    })
    changingSpan.addEventListener('animationend', function() {
    changingSpan.classList.remove('animation-span');
    })
  }, 4000);
```

```css
.changing-span-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    transition: width .2s ease, height .2s ease;
}

.changing-span {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #c82929;
}

.animation-span {
    animation: moveDown 1s ease;
}

@keyframes moveDown {
    0% {opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="first-heading">The <span class="changing-span-wrapper"><span class="changing-span">best</span></span> burgers in town.</h1>
```